# ADL does not work in constexpr functions (clang only)

Tags: c++, templates, clang, constexpr, argument-dependent-lookup

The following code compiles with MSVC and gcc, but not with clang. Why is that so?

It seems like if ADL would not work if `CallFoo ()` is `constexpr`. See the comment.

```
template <class T>
constexpr void CallFoo  ()          // Remove constexpr to fix clang compilation error.
{
    Foo (T ());
}


class Apple {};


int main ()
{
    CallFoo<Apple> ();
}


constexpr void Foo (Apple)
{
}
```

Clang error message ([see on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/9Gh5LG)):

```
<source>:4:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Foo'
    Foo (T ());
    ^
<source>:13:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'CallFoo<Apple>' requested here
    CallFoo<Apple> ();
    ^
```

Comment: Clang enforces the rule that functions must be declared before they are instantiated by a template, move your function declaration higher up and it'll probably work

Comment: Neither of the three compilers enforce this. If you remove `constexpr` in the commented line, all thee compile it successfully.

Comment: An extremely bizarre observation!

Answer (score 1):

Declaration should be visible at the point of instantiation, so clang has right to reject your code. Reordering functions fixes compilation:

```
constexpr void Foo (Apple)
{
}

int main ()
{
    CallFoo<Apple> ();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/R6cRlW)

Fact is that end of file is a point of instantiation too, and gcc/MSVC should only consider this one :/

Comment: Neither of the three compilers enforce that declarations should be visible at the point of instantiation. If you remove `constexpr` in the commented line, all thee compile it successfully.